# 31.0.0 is not a valid SDK Version. Option are 26.0.0 Unversioned

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, expo, android-studio-3.0

I can no longer run my app after updating expo version to 31.0.0. I needed this upgrade to do due iOS version 12 support. Thou after trying to build the Android app it is no longer working.

my package.json looks as below:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.13.1",
    "jest-expo": "^31.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^31.0.4",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-image-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.1.4",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^3.9.3",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.11"
  }
}
```

app.json looks like:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "31.0.0",
    "name": "myapp",
    "slug": "myapp",
    "version": "0.1.1",
    "isDetached": true,
    "detach": {
      "scheme": "expe6b74e69f7904f4b8961fc359e0dc1ce",
      "androidExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/android-v2.4.0-sdk26.0.0-e63d9209-070c-4118-b06b-c60e82da0b66.tar.gz"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.myapp"
    }
  }
}
```

Android build.gradle app looks like this.:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.ferrometal12'
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName '0.1.1'
    ndk {
      abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    // Deprecated. Used by net.openid:appauth
    manifestPlaceholders = [
      'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'host.exp.exponent'
    ]
  }
```

Any idea why this is not working on Android anymore?

NOte: before i had expo 26.0.0 I also had targetSdkVersion to 26, after updating expo I also updated targetSdkVersion to 27

UPDATE: This error occurs on emulator, I havent yet tried on real device, but I have the feeling that the same would be on real device too.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Do you find how to fix it?

Comment: I see that you have different sdk versions in package.json and app.json

Comment: I couldnt find any solution yet, how about you?

Comment: @Mizlul just added an answer.

Comment: @Mizlul I just update the sdk of app.json :) And now it works

Comment: @AralRoca can you post your app.json as well as package.json mine is still not working.

Comment: Do `npm i -g expo` to update the version and do in a different folder `expo init`, then copy the app.json and the package.json dependencies versions into your project.

Comment: @AralRoca what is the sdkVersion for you in app.json? for me 31.0.0 not working

Comment: @Mizlul I have 31.0.0 in app.json. The difference is that also I have the `    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz"` on package.json,
`

Comment: thnx I will try to update react native as well

Answer (score 17):

You have to uninstall and then install the Expo on your Android device.

Comment: i dont have expo installed on my android device at all actually!

Comment: Fixed the issue.

Comment: @Mizlul when we choose 'Run on Android Device/emulator', expo first install the 'Expo' App on Emulator and then execute the app. It occurs when Expo-CLI and Expo App is updated. You just need to uninstall Expo App from Emulator and run the project (npm start), it will install the updated version of Expo App on your Emulator. Same is the case of Android phone, you have to Update Expo App on your phone

Answer (score 9):

Updated mobile expo app from play-store in android. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

see the [upgrade walk-trough](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough) ...

```
{
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz",
    "expo": "^31.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0"
}
```

that `sdkVersion` which you've changed, most likely is the Android SDK version and should be:

```
"sdkVersion": "26.0.0"
```

the current maximum would be `28.0.0`, but when it asks for `26.0.0`, this should possibly be used.

Comment: i will give a try into this config

Comment: im getting mismatch javascrip version vs react native

Comment: If you are using expokit, make sure to have the latest version of expokit in your package.json as well.

Answer (score 1):

Good day,

**THIS IS WORKING**

1. ***If you are using android studio***

> uninstall expo in the virtual android device.
> If you are not sure how
> to uninstall you can delete the virtual device in **Android Virtual
> Device Manager** so that all things are refreshed.
> Reinstall the virtual device again

2. ***If you are using a real android device***

> find the expo and uninstall it.

Comment: @AndriyFM I'm glad it helps

Answer (score 0):

My app is detached / ejected and I am using ExpoKit. The following configuration worked for me:

in `package.json`

```
"expo": "^31.0.6",
"expokit": "31.0.2",
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.1.tar.gz",
```

in `app.json`

`"sdkVersion": "31.0.0"`

and seeing the [upgrade walk-through](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem today ; my Expo Android app brought this error after playstore updated this app.

I resolved the problem by installing an older version of Expo APP *(You can find older versions of playstore apps on [apkpure.com](https://apkpure.com))* and downloading Expo Android App of version 2.12 which supports SDK 31.0.0

Answer (score 0):

## This step is for ejected expo projects:

If you have run `expo update 35.0.0` or other version and it did not solve the error, and if you had ejected your expo project...

Check if you have the right detach properties in your `app.json`. Note the sdk number on the URL for both `iosExpoViewURL` and `androidExpoViewURL` keys.

```
"detach": {
  "iosExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/ios-v2.13.0-sdk35.0.0-a30ebc9b-3db4-42f4-b677-e468076baf18.tar.gz",
  "androidExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/android-v2.13.0-sdk35.0.0-b816b7af-88da-4ca9-87a5-7438f0c21b6e.tar.gz"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.The issue was solved by clearing data and cache of Expo app on Android device. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue just migrate to the latest version of node and expo cli. Uninstall expo on your phone and make a fresh install from the app store. You should be good to go.